# Accessing a view that has a shared ID within shared layouts when only one layout is visible

Tags: android

In my Android app I have a layout for an activity that presents a choice.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/choices" />

    <include layout="@layout/choice_one" />
    <include layout="@layout/choice_two" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In `layout/choices` the user sees two buttons. One button shows `layout/choice_one` and the other shows `layout/choice_two`. (The parent in `layout/choice_one` and `layout/choice_two` is initially set to `android:visibility=gone`.)

So when a user chooses either `choice_one` or `choice_two`, essentially I'm setting the visibility to `VISIBLE`. That works great.

The issue is that inside of both `choice_one` and `choice_two` I have shared elements with the same ID. For example I have a `TextView` with ID `header`. (I did this because I figured only one of those layouts would be visible and they use the same things.)

The issue is that I use Butterknife, and it seems like if I Bind `header`, when I set the visibility on `choice_one` or `choice_two`, I have a 50/50 chance of correctly calling `header.setText("Blah")` on the appropriate `header` element.

I'm sure I can get around this by giving unique IDs to all elements in the layouts or ditching Butterknife and using `findViewById` instead. But is there another way I can target a shared ID inside of a layout without ditching Butterknife or my shared layouts?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. (Writing it out helped, so I'll keep it here in case someone else stumbles upon it.) Instead of using `include` in xml and inflating layouts there, I just subclassed `ViewGroup` for my two layouts and added them to `wrapper`:

```
ChoiceOne choiceOne = new ChoiceOne();
wrapper.addView(choiceOne);
```